# Smallest number with a given number of factors

Tags: number-theory, factoring, divisibility

From my rather rudimentary explorations of this fascinating problem, I believe it to be a layered and rewarding subject for investigation.

My question, essentially, is: *How do you find the smallest number with a given number of factors?* Indeed, as quickly becomes apparent, a distinction is called for between **exactly** a given number of factors and **at least** a given number of factors; as such, approaches considering both will be appreciated.

It's a fairly standard result in number theory that the number of distinct factors (including $1$ and itself) of some number $N$, where
$$
N = p_1^{a}\cdot\ p_2^{b}\cdot\ p_3^{c} \cdots  
$$
($p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3\ldots$ being distinct primes) is 
$$
(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\cdots
$$

Thus, stated mathematically, the question appears to resolve into finding, or rather, finding a method of finding, this:
$$
\min\{N = 2^{a}\cdot\ 3^{b}\cdot\ 5^{c} \cdots \space| \space (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\cdots = n \}
$$
or, as the case may be, this:
$$
\min\{N = 2^{a}\cdot\ 3^{b}\cdot\ 5^{c} \cdots \space| \space (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\cdots \geq n \}
$$
($n$ being the given number of factors).

My crude, trial-and-error approach so far has been factorising $n$ into $n = n_1\cdot n_2\cdot n_3\cdots \space$  and then assigning $a = n_1 - 1,\space b = n_2 - 1,\space c = n_3 - 1,\space \ldots \space$ to get $N$, my only defence being that I tried to factorise sensibly and perceive some sort of pattern or rule at play. I have been unable to obtain anything beyond some common-sense tricks and techniques, though some of them seemed tantalisingly concrete.

I think it's a beautiful problem, and I'm looking for a way of solving it using a clever, universal algorithm. I'd greatly appreciate a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Fermat studied this problem around 1640 — you can read his solution in most reference books (e.g., Mahoney).

Answer (score 5):

For the at least case, you should check out [OEIS sequence A002182](http://oeis.org/A002182) which lists the numbers which set records for number of factors.  Many references are given.  For exactly equal, see [A005179](http://oeis.org/A005179) which has the smallest number with a given number of divisors.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Unfortunately, the references aren't really of much use to me because I cannot seem to access them in their entirety, and (perhaps primarily) because I find it difficult to follow professional mathematics papers, being inexperienced in the field.

Comment: @Aravind:  it is a good way to learn some math.  You can also play around with it.  Increasing $a$ by 1 increases $N$ by a factor 2 and increases the number of factors by $\frac {a+1}a$  If you take logs, you could say the cost of new factors is $\frac {\log (a+1) - \log a}{\log 2}$.  This forms the basis of a greedy algorithm-sequentially add in the next prime that is cheapest in this view.  It will get you most of A002182 and it is fun to see what it misses.

Comment: Aravind, you can either play around with it with the methods you know, or you can put in the effort to learn the methods that give the best results.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Nice. Gerry Myerson: Indeed. I completely agree with both of you, and I take it in the right spirit. It's only that I _have_ tried playing around and was getting nowhere; rest assured, though, I haven't explored this nearly as much as it seems I ought to.