# Quadrinomial with large numbers factorization

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I was looking for a way to factor quadrinomial with large numbers without using the remainder theorem to check each factor, for example:

$$x^3+300x^2+30000x-953125$$

Is there a way to quickly find the factor?, or I must check each $953125$ factors with the remainder theorem until I get 0 remainder?

Comment: Have you tried the old Wolfram Alpha method?

Comment: @AvZ do you have a link, I couldn't find any...

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$953125=61\cdot 5^6$, so only has $28$ factors (counting positive and negative).  On the positive side, since all the terms containing $x$ are positive, the polynomial will continue to grow with $x$.  By considering the linear and constant terms, you need $x$ to be around $30$, so I would check $x-25$ and be done.  It turns out to work.  When $x$ is negative, $300x^2$ is the only positive term, so it needs to equal the sum of all the rest.  The linear term requires $x \lt -100$ and the cubic term requires $x \gt -300$.  There are no factors in that range.  Having found $x=25$ is a root, you could also divide it out to get a quadratic, check the discriminant, and know the roots are complex.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B300*x%5E2%2B30000*x-953125%3D0) is the check in Alpha

Comment: Ross, thank you for you answer, can you please explain how did you figure out the number of factors?

Comment: The result based on the prime factorization is given [in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144696/smallest-number-with-a-given-number-of-factors). In our case, we have $(1+1)(6+1)=14$ positive factors and the same number of negative ones.

Comment: I understand, thank you Ross.

Comment: Ross, I couldn't figure out what do you mean by saying "By considering the linear and constant terms, you need x to be around 30", how did you figure out that the factor should be around 30?, is there a method?, I'm sorry to bother you, but if you can link me to an explanation about the method to figure out that its should be around x(in your answer around 30) I will be very thankful.

Comment: I just asked how big $x$ has to be for the linear and constant terms to add to zero, divided $953125/30000$ in my head and got $30$.  It is really closer to $32$.  Then I looked at the quadratic and cubic terms and noticed that they would be rather smaller than the linear term for $x \approx 30$, so that is a reasonable approximation for one root.  We already knew there is only one positive root.